# How to iterate over List of paths from text file

Tags: java, file, recursion

I have a text file which contains list of paths of folders.

I want to find how many files present in each folder with a special string i.e. any string.

For one path I am able to list out all files present in folder but my question is how to find it for all paths?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    File[] fiels = new File("D:\\html").listFiles();

    for (File file : fiels) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            result.add(file.getName());
        }
    }

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: How are the paths stored in the file?  Are they plain text?  Are they each on their own line?

Comment: Just do the same you do at the moment, with a loop wrapped around it that iterates over an array of the read paths?

Answer (score 2):

Extract your current code, and call it if the `File` is a directory.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    File[] files = new File("D:\\html").listFiles();

    locateFiles(result, files);

    System.out.println(result);
}

private static void locateFiles(List<String> result, File[] files) {
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            result.add(file.getName());
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            locateFiles(result, file.listFiles());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the program in performing same set of functions on the directory and its sub directory. It makes sense to solve the problem using recursion. In recursion a function calls itself again and again until it is precessed all directories and files under given base path.

```
static List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args)  {
  listFiles(new File("D:\\html"));

  for (String result: results)
    System.out.println(result);
}
private static void listFiles(File dir) {
    //Get list of all files and folders in directory
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();

    //For all files and folders in directory
    for(File file: files){
        //Check if directory
        if(file.isDirectory())
            //Recursively call file list function on the new directory
            listFiles(file);
        else
           results.add(file.getAbsolutePath());        
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a `folderPath.txt` which has a list of Directory like this.

> D:\305172
>
> D:\Deployment
>
> D:\HeapDumps
>
> D:\Program Files
>
> D:\Programming

This code gives you what you want + you can Modify it according to your need

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    List<String> foldersPath = new ArrayList<String>();
    File folderPathFile = new File("C:\\Users\\ankur\\Desktop\\folderPath.txt");

    /**
     * Read the folderPath.txt and get all the path and store it into
     * foldersPath List
     */
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(folderPathFile));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while(line != null){
        foldersPath.add(line);
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
    reader.close();

    /**
     * Map the path(i.e Folder) to the total no of 
     * files present in that path (i.e Folder)
     */
    Map<String, Integer> noOfFilesInFolder = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String pathOfFolder:foldersPath){
        File[] files2 = new File(pathOfFolder).listFiles();//get the arrays of files
        int totalfilesCount = files2.length;//get total no of files present
        noOfFilesInFolder.put(pathOfFolder,totalfilesCount);
    }

    System.out.println(noOfFilesInFolder);
}

}
```

Output:

`{D:\Program Files=1, D:\HeapDumps=16, D:\Deployment=48, D:\305172=4, D:\Programming=13}`